# Netbeans 12.1 menu fonts too small, --fontsize no longer works in /etc/netbeans.conf for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: netbeans, fonts, font-size

Netbeans 12.1 no longer respects the `--fontsize` directive in the `/etc/netbeans.conf` config file.

The menu fonts are way too small on a large screen.

Yet setting `Preferences->LXQt Settings->Font->Point` size in the Ubuntu control menu, which is normally respected by most Unix app windows, does not carry through either.

And although Netbeans's
`Tools->Options->Fonts & Colors->Profile: NetBeans->Syntax->All Languages->Default -> Font`
setting changes the font for the code itself inside the editor, it doesn't change the IDE menus.

You would think, after all these years, that there would be a command inside the Options to change the menu font size, but it's still not there yet.
And now editing config to change the `--fontsize` startup option is no longer respected.

How best to change the size of all the system fonts in the Netbeans IDE display environment?

Comment: in file netbeans.conf add --fontsize  to netbeans_default_options

Answer (score 2):

Running netbeans from commandline with an additional argument `--fontsize 12` works for me. Open a console and go the bin directory of netbeans and use the command `./netbeans --fontsize 12`. Change the font size to whatever suits you.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found so far is to change the Look & Feel.

Invoking `aptitude install netbeans` currently (Sept '20) gives version 10, which breaks with a jcraft/jsch error, also "could not successfully run the /usr/bin/g++ compiler" on my system even though g++ is perfectly fine and protections cleared, also "Build Host not connected", after C++ is installed from the 8.2 repository.  Tastes like some kind of jdk error (I've got /usr/lib/jvm both 8 and 11 jdks installed, hard to believe it can't find them). But if the install doesn't work right out of the box, it's a bad sign.  So I tried `snap install netbeans --classic` . This gets version 12.

Netbeans version 12 comes with the `Metal` Look & Feel configured by default.  Changing this to the `GTK+` look and feel, using `Tools->Options->Appearance->Look and Feel->GTK+` with a restart, finally got the menus to the correct system size.

Unfortunately, the Help->About popup still does not respect this, having minuscule fonts.  Perhaps there is a better way?

Although "Look and Feel" is an improvement, I would still like to see direct control of the IDE menu fonts.  From the Options Fonts & Colors menu.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans in `Tools->Options->Appearance->Look and Feel`, I could solve the problem.
But in my case, the selected option already was `GTK+`. Changing to `Metal` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Install Netbeans 13.

It should help